# ffmpeg concat command of many files loses quality or makes result video to stall

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, bmp, mkv

I have a Project that intends to have the union of several images and several videos converted to mp4 output.
Source images come from a Windows App that converted bmps to jpgs.  Those images were converted to mp4 using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -report  -framerate 1/7 -i source.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p  destination.mp4
```

Result video can be seen without problems.

Source videos come from a vms in mkv format and are converted into mp4 using the following:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy destination.mp4
```

As a result I have a series for different mp4 files that are copied to a txt file which will allow us to make a concatenation into a result mp4.

The contents of txt will be something like this (jpgs should be placed alternately to videos) :

```
file '1_VideoMkvto.mp4'
file '2_VideoMkvto.mp4'
file '3_BmptoJpg.mp4'
file '4_VideoMkvto.mp4'
file '5_BmptoJpg.mp4'
file '7_VideoMkvto.mp4'
file '8_JpgtoMp4.mp4'
....
```

I use the following instruction:

```
  ffmpeg -report -f concat -i allVideos.txt -c copy results.mp4
```

The issue that I'm experiencing is that in joined video, videos created originally from images (they were originally bmps converted to jpg) show problems like not being shown, shown for more or less time than original video or even worse... they make video player to stall when their part is played or closed without warning.

Pd.  I tried to concat all videos into one single file and all jpgs-mp4 into one single file and individually they can be seen easily, but when joined together, that's when everything starts to fail.

Raw jpg:

```
"D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" -loop 1 -i "D:\\Project2\\files
\\12278\\PRU_SONOMETRO.jpg" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -y -vf "fps=7,format=yuv420p" "D:\
\Project2\\files\\12278\\Video\\PRU_SONOMETRO.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-76456-g6df2c94 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
libavcodec     57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
libavformat    57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 14.101 /  6. 14.101
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mjpeg @ 008e3300] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0
Input #0, image2, from 'D:\\Project2\\files\\12278\\PRU_SONOMETRO
.jpg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 31662 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080,
25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 00931d20] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range
correctly
[libx264 @ 00900de0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 00900de0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 00900de0] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Cop
yleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb
lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 m
e_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro
ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 i
nterlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=7 scenecu
t=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0
qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\\Project2\\files\\12278\\Video\\PRU_SONOME
TRO.mp4':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.14.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1
080, q=-1--1, 7 fps, 14336 tbn, 7 tbc
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc57.14.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mjpeg @ 008e5700] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0
    Last message repeated 18 times
[mjpeg @ 008e5700] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0me=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
    Last message repeated 18 times
[mjpeg @ 008e5700] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0me=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
    Last message repeated 18 times
[mjpeg @ 008e5700] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0me=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
    Last message repeated 17 times
[mjpeg @ 008e5700] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0me=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
    Last message repeated 17 times
[mjpeg @ 008e5700] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0me=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
    Last message repeated 17 times
[mjpeg @ 008e5700] ignoring invalid SAR: 0/0me=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
    Last message repeated 16 times
frame=   35 fps=6.1 q=-1.0 Lsize=     212kB time=00:00:04.71 bitrate= 368.6kbits
/s
video:211kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
verhead: 0.582017%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] frame I:1     Avg QP:10.59  size:211484
[libx264 @ 00900de0] frame P:9     Avg QP:19.90  size:   194
[libx264 @ 00900de0] frame B:25    Avg QP:30.36  size:    82
[libx264 @ 00900de0] consecutive B-frames:  2.9%  5.7%  0.0% 91.4%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] mb I  I16..4:  1.4% 95.8%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%
0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.5%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%
direct: 0.0%  skip:99.7%  L0:42.3% L1:57.7% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] 8x8 transform intra:95.8% inter:73.4%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 92.7% 31.6% 11.8% inter: 0.0% 0.1%
0.0%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 10% 51% 37%  2%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13% 15% 54%  3%  2%  2%  3%
3%  4%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 30% 20%  3%  3%  3%  2%
3%  5%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 56% 23% 20%  1%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] ref P L0: 94.3%  0.0%  2.7%  3.1%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] ref B L0: 83.1% 15.0%  2.0%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] ref B L1: 88.4% 11.6%
[libx264 @ 00900de0] kb/s:344.46
```

mkv converted to mp4:

```
D:\>"D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" -i "D:\\Project2\\files\\12278\
\46_REGISTROSALIDA1.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k "D:\\Project2\\CDA\
\SicovCDA\\files\\12278\\video\\46_REGISTROSALIDA1.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-76456-g6df2c94 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
libavcodec     57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
libavformat    57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 14.101 /  6. 14.101
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[matroska,webm @ 02fa0d40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video:
mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'D:\\Project2\\files\\12278\\46_REG
ISTROSALIDA1.mkv':
Metadata:
    encoder         : MilestoneMux
Duration: 00:03:17.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 994 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:
1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, SA
R 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (D:\\Pro
ject2\\files\\12278\\video\\46_REGISTROSALIDA1.mp4) has not been
used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video o
ption with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder whic
h was not actually used for any stream.
File 'D:\\Project2\\files\\12278\\video\\46_REGISTROSALIDA1.mp4'
already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[mp4 @ 05d02580] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container fo
rmat requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\\Project2\\files\\12278\\video\\46_REGISTR
OSALIDA1.mp4':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.14.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p, 1920x1080
[SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 5940 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   24016kB time=00:03:17.97 bitrate= 993.8kbits
/s
video:23960kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 0.234450%
```

jpg(originally bmp) to mp4:

```
    "D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" -loop 1 -i "D:\\Project2\\files
\\12278\\Sensorial.jpg" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -y -vf "fps=7,format=yuv420p" "D
:\\Project2\\files\\12278\\Video\\Sensorial.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-76456-g6df2c94 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
libavcodec     57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
libavformat    57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 14.101 /  6. 14.101
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'D:\\Project2\\files\\12278\\39_BmpSensori
al.jpg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25444 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080
[SAR 96:96 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 058663a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range
correctly
[libx264 @ 00df0020] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00df0020] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 00df0020] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 00df0020] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Cop
yleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb
lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 m
e_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro
ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 i
nterlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=7 scenecu
t=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0
qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\\Project2\\files\\12278\\Video\\39_BmpSens
orial.mp4':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.14.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1
080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 7 fps, 14336 tbn, 7 tbc
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc57.14.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   35 fps= 11 q=-1.0 Lsize=      83kB time=00:00:04.71 bitrate= 144.7kbits
/s
video:82kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ov
erhead: 1.497583%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] frame I:1     Avg QP:13.49  size: 80298
[libx264 @ 00df0020] frame P:9     Avg QP: 9.09  size:   127
[libx264 @ 00df0020] frame B:25    Avg QP: 8.68  size:    75
[libx264 @ 00df0020] consecutive B-frames:  2.9%  5.7%  0.0% 91.4%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] mb I  I16..4: 51.4% 39.7%  8.8%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%
0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%
direct: 0.0%  skip:99.9%  L0:44.9% L1:55.1% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] 8x8 transform intra:39.7% inter:17.3%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 7.1% 9.4% 8.8% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.
0%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] i16 v,h,dc,p: 79% 18%  3%  0%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 57% 36%  6%  0%  0%  0%  0%
0%  0%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 28% 13%  3%  5%  6%  6%
4%  6%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] i8c dc,h,v,p: 83% 12%  4%  1%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] ref P L0: 88.9%  1.7%  2.7%  6.8%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] ref B L0:  4.2% 95.8%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] ref B L1: 98.3%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 00df0020] kb/s:133.30
```

final trimmed concat output:

```
    ffmpeg started on 2016-04-27 at 16:06:45
Report written to "ffmpeg-20160427-160645.log"
Command line:
"D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" -report -f concat -i "D:\\Project2\\files\\12297\\control.txt" -c copy "D:\\Project2\\files\\12297\\12297resultado.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-76456-g6df2c94 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavcodec     57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
  libavformat    57. 14.100 / 57. 14.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 14.101 /  6. 14.101
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'concat'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'D:\Project2\files\12297\control.txt'.
Reading option '-c' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option 'D:\Project2\files\12297\12297resultado.mp4' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file D:\Project2\files\12297\control.txt.
Applying option f (force format) with argument concat.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: D:\Project2\files\12297\control.txt.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] rfps: 7.000000 0.000016
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] rfps: 7.000000 0.000016
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] rfps: 14.000000 0.000063
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] rfps: 14.000000 0.000063
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] rfps: 21.000000 0.000143
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] rfps: 21.000000 0.000143
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] rfps: 28.000000 0.000253
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] rfps: 28.000000 0.000253
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 7702749 bytes read:39314 seeks:1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 71010 bytes read:110276 seeks:2 frames:1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[concat @ 00ad1a00] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 2586 bytes read:2586 seeks:0

---comment > file 0 of type mkv converted to mp4


[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:0 stream:0 pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:0 dts_time:0 -> pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:0 dts_time:0
[concat @ 00ad1a00] All info found
[concat @ 00ad1a00] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 2586 bytes read:2586 seeks:0 frames:1
Input #0, concat, from 'D:\Project2\files\12297\control.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 509 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng), 1, 1/16000: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 509 kb/s, 7.01 fps, 7 tbr, 16k tbn, 32k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file D:\Project2\files\12297\12297resultado.mp4.
Applying option c (codec name) with argument copy.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: D:\Project2\files\12297\12297resultado.mp4.
Successfully opened the file.
[mp4 @ 00ae7780] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\Project2\files\12297\12297resultado.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.14.100
    Stream #0:0(eng), 0, 1/16000: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 509 kb/s, 7.01 fps, 7 tbr, 16k tbn, 16k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:0 stream:0 pts:2288 pts_time:0.143 dts:2288 dts_time:0.143 -> pts:2288 pts_time:0.143 dts:2288 dts_time:0.143
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:0 stream:0 pts:1929280 pts_time:120.58 dts:1929280 dts_time:120.58 -> pts:1929280 pts_time:120.58 dts:1929280 dts_time:120.58
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:0 stream:0 pts:1931568 pts_time:120.723 dts:1931568 dts_time:120.723 -> pts:1931568 pts_time:120.723 dts:1931568 dts_time:120.723
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:0 stream:0 pts:1933856 pts_time:120.866 dts:1933856 dts_time:120.866 -> pts:1933856 pts_time:120.866 dts:1933856 dts_time:120.866


----comment > file 2 of type bmp to jpg converted to mp4

[AVIOContext @ 00adbca0] Statistics: 2574258 bytes read, 2 seeks
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 94491 bytes read:35717 seeks:1
[h264 @ 00b73c20] user data:"x264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00"
[h264 @ 00b73c20] no picture 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 73972 bytes read:109641 seeks:2 frames:1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00adb460] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:2 stream:0 pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:-1024 dts_time:-0.0666667 -> pts:2808269 pts_time:182.83 dts:2807245 dts_time:182.763
[mp4 @ 00ae7780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 2925280, current: 2807245; changing to 2925281. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:2 stream:0 pts:2048 pts_time:0.133333 dts:-512 dts_time:-0.0333333 -> pts:2810317 pts_time:182.963 dts:2807757 dts_time:182.797
[mp4 @ 00ae7780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 2925281, current: 2807757; changing to 2925282. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:2 stream:0 pts:1024 pts_time:0.0666667 dts:0 dts_time:0 -> pts:2809293 pts_time:182.897 dts:2808269 dts_time:182.83
[mp4 @ 00ae7780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 2925282, current: 2808269; changing to 2925283. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.


----comment > file 6 of type jpg converted to mp4

[AVIOContext @ 00adbca0] Statistics: 347409 bytes read, 2 seeks
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00ae8f40] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00ae8f40] ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00ae8f40] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 164080 bytes read:36076 seeks:1
[h264 @ 04240060] user data:"x264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00"
[h264 @ 04240060] no picture 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00ae8f40] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00ae8f40] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 144712 bytes read:180740 seeks:2 frames:1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00ae8f40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:6 stream:0 pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:-1024 dts_time:-0.0666667 -> pts:5495132 pts_time:357.756 dts:5494108 dts_time:357.689
[mp4 @ 00ae7780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 5724096, current: 5494108; changing to 5724097. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:6 stream:0 pts:2048 pts_time:0.133333 dts:-512 dts_time:-0.0333333 -> pts:5497180 pts_time:357.889 dts:5494620 dts_time:357.723
[mp4 @ 00ae7780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 5724097, current: 5494620; changing to 5724098. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 00ae7780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 5724304, current: 5600604; changing to 5724305. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[concat @ 00ad1a00] file:6 stream:0 pts:107008 pts_time:6.96667 dts:105984 dts_time:6.9 -> pts:5602140 pts_time:364.723 dts:5601116 dts_time:364.656
[mp4 @ 00ae7780] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 5724305, current: 5601116; changing to 5724306. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.


--- comment  end of process after 39 streams

No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame=40348 fps=4628 q=-1.0 Lsize=  166581kB time=00:38:21.91 bitrate= 592.8kbits/s    
video:166231kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.210593%
Input file #0 (D:\Project2\files\12297\control.txt):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 40348 packets read (170220039 bytes); 
  Total: 40348 packets (170220039 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (D:\Project2\files\12297\12297resultado.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 40348 packets muxed (170220039 bytes); 
  Total: 40348 packets (170220039 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 00ae85e0] Statistics: 34 seeks, 42736 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 00af0ca0] Statistics: 3921256 bytes read, 0 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 00ac0d80] Statistics: 2586 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Comment: You need to show the complete console output for each `ffmpeg` command. Why are the BMP images converted to JPG? This seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: Hi i will paste console output for every type (jpeg, mkv and final join) . As they're extremely large, I don't think output for all files is necesary.  Regarding the step of bmp conversión, that is done at C# code.  I've tried converting to png, bmp and finally to jpeg.  I thought that probably jpgs behave better as some of image files are pictures from cameras (jpegs) that are correctly shown in final result.  I have observed that bmps do not show well in final result.

Comment: I wanted to paste output log but the contents of just one file is way beyond to what's allowed in a case.. is there another way to send those files?

Comment: I removed -report option to have a better output size.  I'm pasting results now

Comment: Results concatenation output report has more tan 50.000 lines.. can I share it another way?

Comment: You may trim lines that repeat, or cut out the large chunk from the middle.

Comment: I uploaded a sample from every type of file from output